# How do I turn SQL logging on in Postgres 8.2?

Tags: database, postgresql

I've got the following settings in my postgres conf:

log_destination = 'stderr'

redirect_stderr = on

log_directory = '/tmp/psqlog'

log_statement = 'all'

And yet no logs are logged. What am I missing here? There is reference on the internet to a variable called "logging_collector", but when I try and set that, postgres dies on startup with a FATAL: unknown variable.

This is on MacOS 10.4.

Ta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to change log_destination to "syslog" or a specific directory. Output that goes to stderr will just get tossed out. Here's the link to the doc page, but I'll see if I can find an example postgresql.conf somewhere http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-logging.html

This mailing list entry provides some info on setting up logging with syslog http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2004-03/msg00381.php

Also, if you're building postgres from source, you might have better luck using a os x package from [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Doing all of the configuration yourself can be tricky for beginners, but the packages normally give you a good base to work from.